# Как получить значение свойства класса в контроллере и передать в Url.Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Все привет. Есть код:

```
public class Class1
{
   public string Name {get; set; }
}

protected override NavItem[] getMyTabs()
    {
            object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Class1));

            PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = typeof(Class1).GetProperty("Name");

            string value = (string)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);

            return new[]{
                new ItemTab("Моя ссылка", Url.Action("Default", "Home", new {name = m} )),
            };
        }
```

Как получить значение свойства класса в контроллере и передать полученное значение в параметр `name Url.Action`?

Comment: @Demon, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, объекты вашего класса где-то хранятся (скорее всего в БД). Тогда логично будет написать хелпер, который сможет делать выборку этих объектов. Соответственно, такой хелпер можно (и, скорее всего, будет нужно) расширить для фильтрации.

Тогда в контроллере вы напишите что-то типа

```
var collection = myHelper.GetEntities(_condition_);
```

И уже с объектами этой коллекции сможете спокойно работать.

Comment: да объекты храняться в бд и значения из бд заносятся в свойства класса, извините мало опыта как написать подобный хелпер? и ещё вопрос у меня есть переменная на странице при переходе на другую страницу, а затем возврата на предыдущую страницу значение переменной теряется, как его получить и использовать в дальнейшем на любой другой странице, можете показать пример?

Comment: не понял вопроса. как достучаться к БД вы, по видимому, знаете. Ну вот и создайте static метод, который возвращает коллекцию объектов вашего класса, заполняемую select'ом из БД. а в контроллере вызовите этот метод.